# How can I get "HelloWorld - BitBake Style" working on a newer version of Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

In the book "Embedded Linux Systems with the Yocto Project", Chapter 4 contains a sample called ["HelloWorld - BitBake style"](http://book.yoctoprojectbook.com/page/code-chapter-4). I encountered a bunch of problems trying to get the old example working against the "Sumo" release 2.5.

If you're like me, the first error you encountered following the book's instructions was that you copied across `bitbake.conf` and got:

```
ERROR: ParseError at /tmp/bbhello/conf/bitbake.conf:749: Could not include required file conf/abi_version.conf
```

And after copying over `abi_version.conf` as well, you kept finding more and more cross-connected files that needed to be moved, and then some relative-path errors after that... Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a series of steps which can allow you to `bitbake nano` based on the book's instructions.

Unless otherwise specified, these samples and instructions are all based on the [online copy of the book's code-samples](http://book.yoctoprojectbook.com/page/code-chapter-4). While convenient for copy-pasting, the online resource is not totally consistent with the printed copy, and contains at least one extra bug.

## Initial workspace setup

This guide assumes that you're working with Yocto release 2.5 ("sumo"), installed into `/tmp/poky`, and that the build environment will go into `/tmp/bbhello`. If you don't the Poky tools+libraries already, the easiest way is to clone it with:

```
$ git clone -b sumo git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git /tmp/poky
```

Then you can initialize the workspace with:

```
$ source /tmp/poky/oe-init-build-env /tmp/bbhello/
```

If you start a new terminal window, you'll need to repeat the previous command  which will get get your shell environment set up again, but it should not replace any of the files created inside the workspace from the first time.

## Wiring up the defaults

The `oe-init-build-env` script should have just created these files for you:

- bbhello/conf/local.conf
- bbhello/conf/templateconf.cfg
- bbhello/conf/bblayers.conf

Keep these, they supersede some of the book-instructions, meaning that you should **not** create or have the files:

- bbhello/classes/base.bbclass
- bbhello/conf/bitbake.conf

Similarly, do **not** overwrite `bbhello/conf/bblayers.conf` with the book's sample. Instead, edit it to add a single line pointing to your own `meta-hello` folder, ex:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/meta-hello \
  /tmp/poky/meta \
  /tmp/poky/meta-poky \
  /tmp/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "
```

## Creating the layer and recipe

Go ahead and create the following files [from the book-samples](http://book.yoctoprojectbook.com/page/code-chapter-4):

- meta-hello/conf/layer.conf
- meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano/nano.bb

We'll edit these files gradually as we hit errors.

## Can't find recipe error

The error:

```
ERROR: BBFILE_PATTERN_hello not defined
```

It is caused by the book-website's `bbhello/meta-hello/conf/layer.conf` being internally inconsistent. It uses the collection-name "hello" but on the next two lines uses `_test` suffixes. Just change them to `_hello` to match:

```
# Set layer search pattern and priority
BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "hello"
BBFILE_PATTERN_hello := "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_hello = "5"
```

Interestingly, this error is not present in the printed copy of the book.

## No license error

The error:

```
ERROR: /tmp/bbhello/meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano/nano.bb: This recipe does not have the LICENSE field set (nano)
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /tmp/bbhello/meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano/nano.bb
```

Can be fixed by adding a license setting with one of the values that bitbake recognizes. In this case, add a line onto `nano.bb` of:

```
LICENSE="GPLv3"
```

## Recipe parse error

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /tmp/bbhello/meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano/nano.bb
[...]
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable PV_MAJOR, expression was ${@bb.data.getVar('PV',d,1).split('.')[0]} which triggered exception AttributeError: module 'bb.data' has no attribute 'getVar'
```

This is fixed by updating the special python commands being used in the recipe, because `@bb.data` was deprecated and is now removed. Instead, replace it with `@d`, ex:

```
PV_MAJOR = "${@d.getVar('PV',d,1).split('.')[0]}"
PV_MINOR = "${@d.getVar('PV',d,1).split('.')[1]}"
```

## License checksum failure

```
ERROR: nano-2.2.6-r0 do_populate_lic: QA Issue: nano: Recipe file fetches files and does not have license file information (LIC_FILES_CHKSUM) [license-checksum]
```

This can be fixed by adding a directive to the recipe telling it what license-info-containing file to grab, and what checksum we expect it to have.

We can follow the way the recipe generates the `SRC_URI`, and modify it slightly to point at the `COPYING` file in the same web-directory. Add this line to `nano.bb`:

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "${SITE}/v${PV_MAJOR}.${PV_MINOR}/COPYING;md5=f27defe1e96c2e1ecd4e0c9be8967949"
```

The MD5 checksum in this case came from manually downloading and inspecting [the matching file](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/COPYING).

## Done!

Now `bitbake nano` ought to work, and when it is complete you should see it built `nano`:

```
/tmp/bbhello $ find ./tmp/deploy/ -name "*nano*.rpm*"
./tmp/deploy/rpm/i586/nano-dbg-2.2.6-r0.i586.rpm
./tmp/deploy/rpm/i586/nano-dev-2.2.6-r0.i586.rpm
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know if it works, but I have to give you an upvote.

Comment: I set `LICENSE="CLOSED" and the `LIC_FILE_CHKSUM` to empty and all worked well.

Comment: Here is my solution: https://github.com/lo-co/embedded-yocto

Comment: `LIC_FILE_CHKSUM` doesn't even need to be defined if `LICENSE="CLOSED"`. See the note at the end if this section: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/licenses.html#specifying-the-lic-files-chksum-variable

Answer (score 1):

I have recently worked on that hands-on hello world project. As far as I am concerned, I think that the source code in the book contains some bugs. Below there is a list of suggested fixes:

**Inheriting native class**

In fact, when you build with bitbake that you got from poky, it builds only for the target, unless you mention in your recipe that you are building for the host machine (native). You can do the latter by adding this line at the end of your recipe:

```
inherit native
```

**Adding license information**

It is worth mentioning that the variable *LICENSE* is important to be set in any recipe, otherwise bitbake rises an error. In our case, we try to build the version 2.2.6 of the nano editor, its current license is GPLv3, hence it should be mentioned as follow:

```
LICENSE = "GPLv3"
```

**Using os.system calls**
As the book states, you cannot dereference metadata directly from a python function. Which means it is mandatory to access metadata through the *d* dictionary. Bellow, there is a suggestion for the do_unpack python function, you can use its concept to code the next tasks (do_configure, do_compile):

```
python do_unpack() {
    workdir = d.getVar("WORKDIR", True)
    dl_dir  = d.getVar("DL_DIR", True)
    p       = d.getVar("P", True)
    tarball_name = os.path.join(dl_dir, p+".tar.gz")

    bb.plain("Unpacking tarball")
    os.system("tar -x -C " + workdir + " -f " + tarball_name)
    bb.plain("tarball unpacked successfully")
}
```

**Launching the nano editor**

After successfully building your *nano editor* package, you can find your nano executable in the following directory in case you are using Ubuntu (arch x86_64):

```
./tmp/work/x86_64-linux/nano/2.2.6-r0/src/nano
```

Should you have any comments or questions, Don't hesitate !